# Is there any latest YAFForum OpenSource?

Tags: .net, forums

All

I downloaded YAF-v1.9.4-RC1-BIN.zip version. but it is not working .

and also added tagprefix in the web.config  file.

```
    <add tagPrefix="YAF" namespace="YAF.Controls" assembly="YAF.Controls, Version=1.9.4.0" />
```

but still some errors occured.
 related to sandbox.

Is there any complete solution for YetAnotherForums? or any alternative Forum Opensources?

Answer (score 1):

Download the latest YAF. it's much more solid and one of the best open source forum solutions for .net (if not the best)